# How to run a SQL query in Cloud Formation template to enable Delayed_Durability in AWS RDS

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-rds

I have a Cloud Formation template to create a SQL DB in the RDS and want to enable Delayed_Durability feature by default in it by running this query:
`ALTER DATABASE dbname SET DELAYED_DURABILITY = FORCED;`

Is there a way to run this query right after db instance is created through CF template?
My CF template looks like this:

```
         "Type":"AWS::RDS::DBInstance",
         "Properties":{  
            "AllocatedStorage":"200",
            "AutoMinorVersionUpgrade":"false",
            "BackupRetentionPeriod":"1",
            "DBInstanceClass":"db.m4.large",
            "DBInstanceIdentifier":"mydb",
            "DBParameterGroupName": {
                    "Ref": "MyDBParameterGroup"
                },
            "DBSubnetGroupName":{  
               "Ref":"dbSubnetGroup"
            },
            "Engine":"sqlserver-web",
            "EngineVersion":"13.00.4422.0.v1",
            "LicenseModel":"license-included",
            "MasterUsername":"prod_user",
            "MasterUserPassword":{ "Ref" : "dbpass" },
            "MonitoringInterval":"60",
            "MonitoringRoleArn": {
               "Fn::GetAtt": [
                  "RdsMontioringRole",
                  "Arn"
               ]
            },
            "PreferredBackupWindow":"09:39-10:09",
            "PreferredMaintenanceWindow":"Sun:08:58-Sun:09:28",
            "PubliclyAccessible": false,
            "StorageType":"gp2",
            "StorageEncrypted": true,
            "VPCSecurityGroups":[  
               {  
                  "Fn::ImportValue":{  
                     "Fn::Sub":"${NetworkStackName}-RDSSecGrp"
                  }
               }
            ],
            "Tags":[  
               {  
                  "Key":"Name",
                  "Value":"my-db"
               }
            ]
         }
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to run this query right after db instance is created through CF template?

Depends. If you want to do it from within CloudFormation (CFN) then sadly, you can't do this using plain CFN. To do it from CFN, you would have to develop a [custom resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html). The resource would be in the form of **lambda function**. You would pass the DB details to the function in your CFN, and it could run and execute your query. It could also return any results you want to your CFN for further use.

In contrast, if you create your CFN stack using **AWS CLI or SDK**, then once `create-stack` call is completed, you can run your query from bash or any programming language you use do deploy your stack.

Comment: Got it. We usually create the stack manually whenever we deploy the application to a new region. I guess the only way would be to create a lambda to run it one time and then delete it once query is executed.

Comment: @tavier If you want to delete it, you can also use one-time instance. So once DB is provision, you create most tiny instance in CFN. In user data your run your query. The trick here is to set its shutdownbehaviour to terminate. With this, once the query finishes, in the userdata you call `shutdown -h now` and the instance terminates automatically. Its a little trick when you want to do something on one-off basis. And its easier to setup then a custom resource that you have to delete later on.

Comment: That sounds like a good idea to make sure that we dispose the resource once done with it. Will give it a try. Thanks for sharing.